# React Native How to send multiple state variables from onClick child to method in parent class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native, transfer

I'm having problems sending over data from my child class to its parent class.

**Child class:**

```
createItem = () => {
  const { newItemName } = this.state;
  const item = { newItemName };

  this.props.addItem(item);
  this.setState({ newItemName: '' });
  this.props.closeModal();
};

// Submit button
onPress={item => this.createItem(item)}
```

**Parent class:**

```
addItem = item => {
  // this.setState({name: item.name, quantity: item.quantity, location: item.location})

  this.setState({ name: item });
};

// Open Modal Button for data entry to be added to list
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.add}
  onPress={item => this.toggleModal(item)}
/>;
```

I'm not sure how to properly send the data over, I just know how to toggle the function in the parent class. I tried looking for answers online but they didn't match my scenario by sending data to a function and then changing the state of the parent class.

Comment: You're passing `item` as an argument, so why not send more args or add more properties to the `item`?

Comment: what is the issue? looking at your code and assuming the child component is a modal and you're passing the `addItem` function, it should work

Comment: The problem is when I try to set the state in the parent class using "this.setState({ name: item });", state is still empty when trying to display it using "{this.state.name}"